# Converting XML to CSV using XSLT Formatting Issue

Tags: csv, xslt

I have the following XML

```
<Data>
    <Employee>
        <Name>
            <FirstName>John</FirstName>
            <LastName>Snow</LastName>
        </Name>
        <DOB>1990-01-01</DOB>
        <Passport>
            <Country>United Kingdom</Country>
            <ID>12345678</ID>
        </Passport>
        <Passport>
            <Country>United States of America</Country>
            <ID>789101112</ID>
        </Passport>
    </Employee>
</Data>
```

And I am converting it as seen below:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Data/Employee">            
            <xsl:value-of select="Name/FirstName"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Name/LastName"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="Passport">
                <xsl:value-of select="Country"/>
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="ID"/>                
                <xsl:text>&#xd;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="DOB"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

The output I am getting is:

```
John,Snow,United Kingdom,12345678
United States of America,789101112
,1990-01-01
```

But I require the passport information to be populated below each other and then DOB to be shown on the top line as seen below:

```
John,Snow,United Kingdom,12345678,1990-01-01
,,United States of America,789101112
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you sure that is the result you want? I would have expected a "flat" file with the name and DOB values duplicated for each passport.

Comment: In addition, which version of XSLT does your processor support?

Comment: No I don't want to duplicate the same information on each line. I want the top line to hold the entire data record and the line underneath to hold only the additional passport information.

Comment: It supports XSLT 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps like this:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/Data">
    <xsl:for-each select="Employee">
        <xsl:for-each select="Passport">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="position()=1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="../Name/(FirstName, LastName), Country,ID, ../DOB" separator=","/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'', '', Country,ID, ''" separator=","/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that I have added a trailing comma in the place of the "missing" DOB.

Comment: This is something that I can work work. What if I had a number of multi instance items within the XML? The above will work for one of them.

Comment: It depends on what exactly the input looks like and what is the result you expect. I suggest you post a new question with your new requirement.

Comment: Yes so say the output also included multiple addresses (Work/Home). Same output, the first address would be on the top line and the second address on the second line

Comment: Sorry, comments are not a good place to discuss this issue.  If you have only multiple addresses, then you can do the same with addresses as I did with passports. If you have multiple passports **and** multiple addresses, then I would need to see the expected result (and understand its logic) before answering. Post a new question.